# "Welcome to the site" for review comments for brand new users

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, new-users

We want to welcome new users to site and encourage them to actively participate to improve the site. Pandering to new users is bad, encouring positive behaviour is good.

For automatic comments from the review queue for Low Quality Posts,

[image: LQP comments]

should we prepend them with:

> "Welcome to stackoverflow. {rest of the message}"

It's a small thing that I see in a lot of manual comments to new users and I'd be interested to see if this inclusion to the clear, objective criticism from the review queue comments encourages them to fix the issues and continue to participate.

Comment: Do those queue have auto comments? Only queue I noticed having them is the LQP.

Comment: That's probably from a stack app called [AutoReviewComments](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se).

Comment: I did mean LQP, I'd not seen AutoReviewComments.

Comment: Looks like it's already a feature in AutoReviewComments `9. The default message is "Welcome to $SITENAME$" - which is shown for any 1-week-old users. By clicking on the 'welcome' link at the bottom of the popup, you can opt to change this message, or leave it empty to show no messages at all. You can also 'force' the message for older users on a one-off basis. This is per-site.`

Comment: I see this verbiage on other sites a lot, and even though I _know_ it's meant well, and even though it's not even directed at me, I can't help but read it as patronizing. I just don't think the jovial "Welcome to $SITE!" mixes properly with corrective advice.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I see a couple of issues here.

1. The low-quality review queue, to which you refer, also processes questions from established users. Nobody is immune from their answer being flagged VLQ or NAA. For such users, "Welcome" would not make sense.
2. Some of the non-answers   deleted from the queue are entirely non-constructive and fall just short of being flagged as abusive. Saying "welcome" feels out of place then.
3. Users who dislike canned niceties in general would be more likely to omit the comment.

The queue processes only answers. First-time answer posters are already told "Thanks for contributing an answer to Stack Overflow!" Maybe that's enough nice words from a can.

Comment: I agree. Saying: "Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here's why your contribution isn't good enough..." is a mixed signal, adding noise to what should be a functional message.

Comment: @TZHX: Well, at least it's better than just blindly upvoting everything or such. Stumbled over someone burning down the FPQ while editing a post to maybe acceptable.

Comment: @TZHX Specifically, it makes the greeting sound insincere or even sarcastic.

Comment: 1. An edit splatted one of the clarifications, it should only be displayed to new users. 2. True. 3. Presumably A/B testing would be able to show whether it was putting off pragmatic newcomers. I'd forgotten they get pleasantries through the answering.

Comment: @Deduplicator I don't see how this change would make people any less likely to do that though...

Comment: The `"Maybe that's enough nice words from a can."` paragraph seals it for me that this isn't really needed. However, I see a lot of new users responding to the comments without knowing they're chosen from a prewritten list (since they're new), so it wouldn't be AS jarring as when you know it's a "beep boop, stop being rubbish in an obvious way" auto comment.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not going through the whole activity history for every single question/answer owner just to decide whether I should welcome him or not. Most people with posts in the review queues are newbies, so per default I just welcome everyone. The most important point of all is actually doing a good review, everything else is sugar. Since we all MUST be polite with the newcomers, I always say Welcome or at least Hi to all of them before pointing out the issues in their posts.